# How to save post_status using action save_post?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, save-post, post-status

I have a custom post status and i'm wondering if it's possible to save changes of post_status using action save_post? Sample codes would be great.

Comment: juste saving `post_status` in the action `save_post` call this action again and create an infinite loop. then edit your question to give more details.

Comment: use this instead https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data